# Naming a nitrile in the middle of an aliphatic chain

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, nitriles

What class of compounds does this belong to, if it exists; $$\ce{CH3-CH2-C\equiv N^{+}- CH3}$$
I honestly don't know if it exists; it popped up in my head while I was reading up on nitrile compounds, and I haven't heard of this type of molecule, thus the question.

If it doesn't exist, why not?

Comment: You appear to have a carbon with 5 bonds in there

Comment: @Waylander: Wouldn't it be $-C\equiv N-$?

Comment: Then you have a N with 4 bonds and no charge

Comment: The charge on the nitrogen was implied, sorry. I didn't know how to do that with MathJax. Does it exist, then?

Comment: Yes. Nitriles can be methylated by a variety of reagents. The N-methyl nitrilium species generated are highly reactive: example https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1980/c3/c39800001151/unauth#!divAbstract

Comment: Just so you know, charges are never implied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compounds like this are named based on the nitrile from which they are derived. So, in your case, the nitrile is propanenitrile:

$$\ce{CH3-CH2-C#N}$$

A protonated nitrile would be called a nitrilium cation, following the general form:

- amine --> ammonium
- imine --> iminium
- nitrile --> nitrilium

Thus, the following cation is named propanenitrilium:

$$\ce{CH3-CH2-C#N^+-H}$$

If we swap that proton with an alkyl group, we can call it an *N*-alkyl substituent. Thus, your cation is the *N*-methylpropanenitrilium cation.

$$\ce{CH3-CH2-C#N^+-CH3}$$